# Is $\partial S \subset S$ the same as $\partial S \bigcap S = \partial S$?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am currently reading Bloch's A First Course in Geometric Topology and Differential Geometry. The notion of open and closed sets came up, and the intuitive definition Bloch made was that open sets do not contain their boundary, and closed sets do. However, this doesn't really cover sets that are half-open or half-closed, or sets that are both open and closed or neither, or infinite sets. After reading proofs on Proof Wiki, I found that 
$$
\text{S is closed} \leftrightarrow \partial S \subset S
$$
However, I also found that 
$$
\text{S is open} \leftrightarrow \partial S \ \cap \ S = \emptyset
$$
These two definitions look different, and after thinking about it, I wondered if
$$
\partial S \subset S \leftrightarrow \partial S \ \cap \ S = \partial S 
$$
Then, the definitions of open and closed would be analogous and elegant (at least to me).

So, is my last statement true for all (or most) $S$? How would I go about proving it? Is this a good definition? Lastly, if anyone has any suggestions for further reading on this topic, I'd be thankful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turns out to have nothing to do with topology, just set theory. If $A,B$ are any two sets, then $A \subset B \iff A \cap B = A$.

Comment: Whoops, shows you how much set theory I know. Is this a result everyone knows or is there a proof of it somewhere?

Comment: @trytryagain Try proving it yourself – it should take a line or two (or a simple Venn diagram, if you prefer a visual approach). Tell me if you get stuck.

Comment: Oh, I see. I made a Venn diagram, and the visual approach really helped me. Thanks for your assistance!